# ASP.NET Core Web API - Exception is not showing immediately in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an exception thrown in my ASP.NET Core Web API project.
And I do get the exception name and stacktrace and everything, but the problem is that I get that **as a response** to the API request, but I want Visual Studio to **take me immediately** to the exception where and when it was thrown, like I have placed a breakpoint to it.

This is something that used to work in regular ASP.NET Core MVC projects, but for some reason it doesn't work in Web API.

Also, to clarify - I don't have any global exception handling filter or middleware, I just call `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` to get the detailed exception in development, this is from my HTTP request pipeline:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();
}
// Other irrelevant middlewares...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you need to set the Visual Studio like this:**

[image]

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698154/force-break-on-any-exception-thrown-in-program/1698165#1698165).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @XinranShen answer I also needed to update the debug settings.

I checked the setting marked below:

[image]